# How to create a scrolling DIV without cropping overflow-x?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a DIV that is only supposed to scroll vertically. I would like to have an element inside this DIV overflow horizontally without being cropped. This is the desired effect:

[image]

I thought that if I only specified `overflow-y:scroll`, it would only crop the vertical overflow. However, I was wrong and this is what really happens:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
ol {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 20em;
    width: 7em;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/u6d6W/1/

Comment: you will have to specify overflow-x:hidden since the default is scroll.

Comment: @Kyle: But that will hide it, not allowing it to show in front of the scrollbar. Right?

Comment: @Adrift : there are two overflow properties: overflow-x and overflow-y. I only specified overflow-y, but for some reason overflow-x is set to hidden...

Answer (score 11):

Interesting question! I thought you just had to specify the `overflow-x` as `visible`, but after trying I found out I was wrong. I've never came across such a situation, so I did some research.

Here is what the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x) says (emphasis mine):

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: **if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’**.

I don't know what's the rationale behind this *spec*, but apparently that is not a bug, but a feature :).

However, I have tested by setting the `overflow-x` to `visible` and the `overflow-y` to `hidden` and it still sets my `overflow-x` to `auto` (which is the scrolling behavior), in Chrome 25. I believe **this** might be a bug.